# I want to know what the function $x^2$ will become if rotated by 45 clockwise about the original point?

Tags: functions

What the function $x^2$ will become if  rotated by 45 clockwise about the original point?

Comment: I would say - coordinate transformation by turning on the desired angle.

Comment: You mean you want to rotate the *graph* of this function, the graph meaning $\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=x^2\}$. It will still be a parabola.

Comment: can give me the new form of x^2 after rotation?

Comment: The rotated curve won't be the graph of function anymore, since it doesn't pass the vertical line test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rotate by $45^\circ$ clockwise then the point $(x,y)$ goes to the point $\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2},\frac{-x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)$ while the point $\left(\frac{-x+y}{\sqrt2},\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)$ goes to the point $(x,y)$.

So the points on the curve $y=x^2$ go to points on the curve $\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2} = \left(\frac{-x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)^2$, i.e. $$\sqrt2 x + \sqrt2 y = (y-x)^2.$$

Multiply this out solve using the quadratic formula and you get $$y = x + 2^{-1/2} \pm \sqrt{2^{3/2}x+2^{-1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The original graph of the function is $\{(t,t^2), t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
After applying rotation matrix with $\theta=\pi/4$, we get $\{(at-at^2,at+at^2), t\in\mathbb{R}\} $ where $ a = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} $.
This curve will not be a function.